# Image is not coming on full screen

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress-theming

I have developed a website it works fine at all. Just my main front image is not coming in full size. I mean not coming on full screen with different resolution.
Please check it on here.
http://kelts.wpengine.com/

It may be some problem with Position or Jquery I am not sure..

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631803/get-full-size-of-image-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Are you asking why it isn't going all the way to the bottom?

Comment: yes ..Can you please see how it could be fix on all screen?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height and width form the class `.section img{}` this may work for as u wished.

Comment: Have tried all these stuffs but somehow it escapes the footer.I need left sidebar , main image,and footer without any white space in between.And I guess it could be done only by the JS.Can you please take a look of that once again?

Comment: give position:relative to the div which has class  tab . Now i am getting only extra space below the image , i am correct.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can fix your problem with the CSS `background-size:cover;`, so don't insert the image with the img-tag, but with the CSS background property.